# System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' when inserting data into a sql database

Tags: c#, .net, razor, razor-pages

I am working on a inventory surplus web app using c# and razor pages that will search for data in our inventory database based off of asset tag number then if it finds something it populates the input fields with related information, but if it does not find anything it returns the fields to enter the information manually then its supposed to insert the information provided into a sql database when the submit button is clicked I am getting this error when it tries to insert the entered information into the database:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Surplus.Pages.FormItems.NewSurplusFormPageModel.CopiedRowNumbers.get returned null.
```

here is my cshtml code:

```
@page
@model Surplus.Pages.FormItems.NewSurplusFormPageModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Surplus Form</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-..." crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <center><h1>@Model.WelcomeMessage</h1></center>

    <div class="container">
        <form method="post">
            <table class="table table-responsive" id="originalFormTable">
                <!-- Original form fields -->
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="assetTag" asp-for="AssetTag" placeholder="Enter CPS Tag Number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" id="building" asp-for="Building" placeholder="Select Building">
                            <option value="">Select Building</option>
                            @foreach (var buildingOption in Model.BuildingOptions)
                            {
                                <option value="@buildingOption">@buildingOption</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" asp-for="Description" placeholder="Enter Item Name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" id="reason" asp-for="Reason" placeholder="Select Reason" onchange="loadInputFields()">
                            <option value="">Select Reason</option>
                            @foreach (var reasonOption in Model.ReasonOptions)
                            {
                                <option value="@reasonOption.CodeID">@reasonOption.ReasonDescription</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <button onclick="copy(this)" type="button" id="searchButton" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Search</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <div id="clonedFormsContainer"></div>

            <div class="container">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var rowNumber = 0;

        function copy(t) {
            rowNumber++;

            var clonedForm = $(t).closest('table').clone();
            $(t).closest('.container').find('#clonedFormsContainer').append(clonedForm);

            // Update the IDs and names of cloned form fields
            clonedForm.find('select').each(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var newId = id + '_' + rowNumber;
                $(this).attr('id', newId);
                $(this).attr('name', newId);
            });

            clonedForm.find('input').each(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var newId = id + '_' + rowNumber;
                $(this).attr('id', newId);
                $(this).attr('name', newId);
            });

            // Clear the cloned form fields
            clonedForm.find('input').val('');
            clonedForm.find('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        }

        function loadInputFields() {
            var reasonCodeID = $('#reason').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/FormItems/NewSurplusFormPageModel?handler=InputFields&reasonCodeID=' + reasonCodeID,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#clonedFormsContainer').html(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my c# code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Surplus.Pages.FormItems
{
    public class NewSurplusFormPageModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString = "Data Source=Dbname;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=username;Password=password;";

        [BindProperty]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string WelcomeMessage { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string AssetTag { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string Building { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public int Reason { get; set; }

        public List<string> BuildingOptions { get; set; }
        public List<Reason> ReasonOptions { get; set; }

        public List<int> CopiedRowNumbers { get; set; } // Track the numbers of copied rows

        public void OnGet(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            // Retrieve user's first and last name (assuming it's available in the session or any other way)
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            WelcomeMessage = $"Welcome, {FirstName} {LastName}!";
            FetchBuildingOptions();
            FetchReasonOptions();

            CopiedRowNumbers = new List<int>();
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    string query = "INSERT INTO SurplusItemsNew (CPSNumber, Description, ReasonCodeID) " +
                                   "VALUES (@cpsNumber, @description, @reasonCodeID); " +
                                   "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpsNumber", AssetTag);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", Description);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reasonCodeID", Reason);

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    // Insert data from copied rows
                    foreach (var rowNumber in CopiedRowNumbers)
                    {
                        string assetTag = Request.Form[$"AssetTag_{rowNumber}"];
                        string description = Request.Form[$"Description_{rowNumber}"];
                        int reasonCodeId = int.Parse(Request.Form[$"Reason_{rowNumber}"]);

                        query = "INSERT INTO SurplusItemsNew (CPSNumber,Description, ReasonCodeID) " +
                                "VALUES (@cpsNumber, @description, @reasonCodeID); " +
                                "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
                        using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpsNumber", assetTag);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reasonCodeID", reasonCodeId);

                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }

                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Database connection failed: {ex.Message}");
                FetchBuildingOptions();
                FetchReasonOptions();
                return Page();
            }

            return RedirectToPage("/ItWorkedPage"); // Redirect to another page after processing
        }

        public IActionResult OnGetInputFields(int reasonCodeID)
        {
            FetchReasonOptions();

            // Perform any logic to determine which input fields should be returned based on the reason code ID

            // Return a partial view with the updated input fields
            return Partial("_InputFieldsPartial", this);
        }

        private void FetchBuildingOptions()
        {
            BuildingOptions = new List<string>();

            // Fetch building options from the database
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    string query = "SELECT BuildingName FROM BuildingList";
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                string buildingName = reader["BuildingName"].ToString();
                                BuildingOptions.Add(buildingName);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Database connection failed: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private void FetchReasonOptions()
        {
            ReasonOptions = new List<Reason>();

            // Fetch reason options from the database
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    string query = "SELECT CodeID, ReasonDescription FROM Reasons";
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                int codeId = (int)reader["CodeID"];
                                string reasonDescription = reader["ReasonDescription"].ToString();
                                ReasonOptions.Add(new Reason { CodeID = codeId, ReasonDescription = reasonDescription });
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Database connection failed: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be amazing!!!!!
thank you in advance!

I tried stepping through it and googling the error

Comment: i did not see all code, but i see you are not creating a new list CopiedRowNumbers = new List<int>();  on Post. (but you creating on get), in aditon, make a default constructor in NewSurplusFormPageModel  to create a new list for that field

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<int> CopiedRowNumbers { get; set; } = new List<int>();
```

Comment: that fixed my error but it is only insetting the 1st rows not the copied rows into the database any idea why? thanks for all your help!!!!!

Comment: Are you sure there is more than 1 item in the list? I need more code. I can't see how `CopiedRowNumbers` is populated

Comment: the copiedrownumbers is in the cshtml code provided above if that's not what you are looking for please let me know what code you are looking for

Comment: There is no CopiedRowNumbers in your cshtml.

If I answered your question please mark as answered.